# My react app keeps rendering and does not respect the if condition

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

I m trying to build an app in which you have to answer multiplication questions and every wrong question is saved and after you reach a certain score ( in this case 2 ) you have to reanswer them for something like a last chance. But i think i might need 2 react apps, but i do not know how to pass the state between them. In my app i try to do everything in one componenet but react keeps rendering after if else statement. Here s my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
    <title>Hello</title></head>

    <style>

        .challenge-container {
            text-align: center;
            font-family:sans-serif;
            font-size:55px;
        }

        input {
            font-size:55px;            
        }
        .correct {
            color:green;
        }

        .incorrect {
            color:red;
        }
    </style>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>



    <script type="text/babel">



        function App() {

            const [state, setState ] = React.useState({
                num1: Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10),
                num2: Math.ceil(Math.random()* 10),
                response: "",
                score: 0,
                status: 1,
                wrongQuestions: []
            });

            function updateResponse(event) {
                setState({
                    ...state,
                    response:event.target.value
                })
            }


            function inputKeyPress(event) {
                if(event.key === "Enter"){
                    const answer = parseInt(state.response);
                    if(answer === state.num1 * state.num2){
                        setState({
                            ...state,
                            score: state.score + 1,
                            response: "",
                            num1: Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10),
                            num2: Math.ceil(Math.random()* 10),
                            status: true
                        })
                    }
                    else {
                        setState({
                            score: state.score - 1,
                            response: "",
                            status: false,
                            wrongQuestions: [...state.wrongQuestions, [state.num1, state.num2]],
                            num1: Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10),
                            num2: Math.ceil(Math.random()* 10)
                        })
                    }
                }
            }

            if(state.score === 2) {
                let solveWrong = state.wrongQuestions;
                setState({
                    ...state,
                    score:0,
                    wrongQuestions: []
                })
                while(solveWrong.length > 0){
                    let tempArr = solveWrong.shift();

                    return (
                        <div className="challenge-container">
                            <p>Let's solve the mistakes!</p>
                            <p className={state.status ? "correct" : "incorrect"}>{tempArr[0]} * {tempArr[1]}</p>
                            <input type="text" className="answer-box" value={state.response} onKeyPress={inputKeyPress} onChange={updateResponse}/>
                            <p>Score: {state.score}</p>    
                        </div>
                    )
                }
            } else {

                return (
                    <div className="challenge-container">
                        <p className={state.status ? "correct" : "incorrect"}>{state.num1} * {state.num2}</p>
                        <input type="text" className="answer-box" value={state.response} onKeyPress={inputKeyPress} onChange={updateResponse}/>
                        <p>Score: {state.score}</p>    
                    </div>
                );
            }
        }

    
      
         ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"));
    
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried to use the if else but it did not work since react keeps rendering not caring about if else. Also i think the while statement might not work.

Comment: I don't think you'd need two React applications for something like this.  You should check out react-redux

Comment: React will re-render your component every time you call `setState`. You should not call setState during render. The `return` within your `while` loop will exit the loop. (And you shouldn't be doing a while loop here in the first place.)